# How to host a minecraft server on offline mode with luck perms

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I get disconnected from the server immediately why?
I want to run the server on offline mode
The server is run on spigot/bukkit

EDIT:
Luckperms has a bug where it cannot run offline in spigot/bukkit, so all I had to do was to change to paper and it worked. (I mean server software)

Comment: Can't you include that you want to do offline mode in the body?

Comment: I thought it wouldn't be needed.......

Comment: It is good to include it.

Answer (score 0):

First stop the server.

Go to the folder in which you installed the server. Go to the file named server-properties.yml and open it using any text editor. Then look for the argument saying online-mode = true and change the true to false. It should look like :

```
online-mode = false
```

Then save the file and turn the server on. Next, go online in the server. Then in the console, type :

```
op Username(your username)
```

to op yourself. Now you should be able to use all commands.

I hope this helped. If not sorry.

Comment: I did this but luckperms doesn't allow me to join it says online mode is off, and if my friends try to join they'll go into creative obvio